# Why does Samsung GS4 pattern lock sometimes change to side-by-side layout?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have the SGS4 SGH-M919, Android 4.2.2,  WickedV8 ROM.

Normally my lock screen looks like this:

[image: Normal Pattern Lock]

Once in a while, my lock screen unexpectedly changes to this side-by-side arrangement:

[image: Unwanted layout]

I have not done anything to cause this change, and I am unable to find a way to change it back to normal other than rebooting the phone.
The "pencil" icon does not cause anything to move.  If I try long enough, a message will appear that says something like "your security settings prevent changes to the lock screen".  I can still unlock the phone, but the small pattern is less convenient.

I do not find anything in Settings that would control the layout of the lock screen. 
Can anyone explain why this changes and how I could prevent it or change it back to normal without a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like it is a bug in the custom ROM you are using. *Many custom ROMs (or Xposed modules) that add a **rotate lock screen** function may have that bug.* If it is disabled, and the bug occurs, there only ways to reverse it are to either restart `com.android.systemui` or to enable auto-rotation of the lock screen and then turn the phone into landscape mode, then back to portrait (it may take several attempts; it may not fix itself at all for both methods).

Alternatively, if you do not have that option, you can install [Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and either the module [Wanam Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/ma.wanam.xposed) for TouchWiz or Gravitybox [JB](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox) / [KK](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox) for AOSP. To change lockscreen rotation settings.

Personally, I recommend adding a shortcut to your homescreen to kill systemui. You can do this by installing an app like [ROM Toolbox Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox). Create a homescreen shortcut from ROM Toolbox (or whichever script app you installed) and make it a script. In the script, issue the command `pkill com.android.systemui`. Make sure that you have **root privileges** and to (if necessary) tell the app to run it with root.

**BUG**: There is an existing bug where, if YouTube is running in the background, may inadvertently cause lockscreen rotation. This can be solved by killing the background process **YouTube**.

Comment: In the ROM controls, I do not find anything like "rotate lock screen."  Where would I look for that setting? I assume I should set it to "Enabled" to avoid the bug? I do not have Xposed.

Comment: If you can't find the setting under **WICKED Rom Control > Tweaks > Lockscreen**, see my updated answer. Also, there is an update to your ROM ([WICKED v10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2265998)) which might fix the bug.